# How to loop through an array to set price based on given dates in `Php`

Tags: php, laravel

There is an array of objects which store the list of cars (data comes from API calls).

How can the prices be dynamically set based on the actual date? (ie: How to compare $today and then set the price if it matches the criteria )

```
For Luxury Price for Honda:- 
From Jan 1 - Aug 26: 6000
From Aug 27 - Aug 31: 4000
From Sep 1 - Sep 30: 8000
From Oct 1 onwards: 4000
```

```
$today = strtotime(Carbon::now()->toDateString()) * 1000;
cars= [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Honda",
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": "100",
          "carId":1000,
          "type": "Luxury",  
          "price": "4000",
          "startdate": 1630058167000, // (Aug 27)

        },
        {
          "id": "101",
          "carId":1000,
          "type": "Luxury",  
          "price": "6000",
        },
        {
          "id": "102",
          "carId":1200,
          "type": "Standard",  
          "price": "2000",
        },
        {
          "id": "103",
          "carId":1000,
          "type": "Luxury",  
          "price": "8000",
          "startdate": 1630490167000, // (Sep 1)
          "enddate": 1632995767000,  // (Sep 30)      
        },
      ],
}
....
];
```

How can `prices` be looped to check if $today date falls in 1 of the categories and then set the price to the given price

Edit- Code attempt

```
$conditionPrice = "";
$today = strtotime(Carbon::now()->toDateString()) * 1000;
foreach ($cars as $car) {
 foreach ($car->prices as $price) {
//case of only startDate present
  if (property_exists($price, 'startDate') && $todayDate >= $price->startDate) {
//if the property is not there - it throws errors
//want $conditionPrice = $price->price; after it checks all the cases to see if $today date falls in that range
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried looping and using PHP `property_exists()` to check if the property exists. Then checking if the date >= startDate && date <= endDate.
However to handle all the cases the conditions just gives the price of the last item in the array.

Comment: Please share more details, like runnable code of your attempt. If you loop over an array, you normally don't need `property_exists`, as `isset` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do same, but with a more complex array_filter on the keys.

Here's how I did it, using a similar method.

```
// Filter out array elements with keys shorter than 4 characters
$a = array(
0      => "val 0", 
"one"  => "val one", 
"two"  => "val two", 
"three"=> "val three", 
"four" => "val four", 
"five" => "val five", 
"6"    => "val 6"
); 
$f = array_filter(array_keys($a), function ($k){ return strlen($k)>=4; }); 
$b = array_intersect_key($a, array_flip($f));
print_r($b);
```

This outputs the result:

```
Array
(
[three] => val three
[four] => val four
[five] => val five
)
```

i hope this will help you .

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's groupBy function and then map the data you want to group it to. non tested :

```
return Model::all()
  ->groupBy('key', function($group) {
    return $group->reduce(fn($acc, $value) => $acc+ $value))
  });
});
```